# Difference in Liquibase Maven/CLI parameters

Tags: liquibase

There are a lot of useful parameters (for example, changelogCatalogName) for Maven update task: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_update.html
But they are not mentioned in CLI page for liquibase update: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html
Is it possible to pass these parameters?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `liquibase --help` to return command line options as well, there may be some on there that were missed in the docs.

I am working on improving consistency and feature parity between different ways to run Liquibase but there can still be some features that have not made it into all modes yet. ChangelogCatalogName and ChangelogSchemaName look like two fields that have not made it into CLI parameters yet, but you are able to specify them by system properties as -Dliquibase.catalogName=ABC and -Dliquibase.schemaName=XYZ

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I missed your answer and was scared that you probably went on vacation before we are ready to go in production with Liquibase :) P.S. I raised a jira with details about it in liquibase tracker.

Comment: No, still around and answering questions.  Good luck with going to production. I'll take a look at the issue.