# Liquibase creates log tables with user schema

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

When implementing liquibase on Sql Server. Below tables are created on USER schema not with DBO schema. Not sure how to fix this.

```
AMAR.DATABASECHANGELOG
AMAR.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
```

It should be

```
DBO.DATABASECHANGELOG
DBO.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
```

I don't have any issues on creating table. It always creates on dbo schema. I'm using integratedSecurity and Liquibase version is 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify

```
--liquibaseSchemaName=dbo
```

as a parameter when running Liquibase from the command line.

I prefer to that into my `liquibase.properties` file.

This works for me using Liquibase 3.5.3 - don't know about 3.4.2 though

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at changelogSchemaName parameters (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/updateSQL-mojo.html) to specify schema where Liquibase stores tables.

Comment: I got following error. Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'changelogSchemaName'. I'm applying sql changes thru command prompt (i.e., liquibase update).

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198515/difference-in-liquibase-maven-cli-parameters Looks like maven/CLI commands are not in sync.